# C++: Error occurs when fmt library is included

Tags: c++, include, fmt

https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt

I'm having trouble using c++ library on ubuntu eclipse. I downloaded the fmt library from github. I followed the steps as described in the documentation section Building the Library. In fmt folder;

```
mkdir build  # Create a directory to hold the build output.
cd build
cmake ..     # Generate native build scripts.
```

After running the commands, makefiles are created in the build array.
To install the library I ran following command.

```
sudo make install
```

After the installation, the necessary files were copied to the /usr/local/ directory. I copied the header files and compiled libfmt.a file to my project directory.
My project hierarchy;

```
fmtTestProject
 |--Debug
 |--src
    |--fmtTest.cpp
 |--include
    |--args.h
    |--chrono.h
    |--color.h
    |--compile.h
    |--core.h
    |--format.h
    |--format-inl.h
    |--os.h
    |--ostream.h
    |--printf.h
    |--ranges.h
    |--std.h
    |--xchar.h
 |--lib
    |--libfmt.a
```

I defined the include files to the eclipse project.

fmtTest -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Compiler -> Includes -> Include paths -> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/include}"

fmtTest -> Properties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> GCC C++ Linker -> Library search path -> "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/lib}"

After the define libraries, I wrote the code in the documentation and compiled it.

```
#include <fmt/core.h>

int main() {
    fmt::print("Hello, world!\n");
}
```

The code compiles without errors. But the problem is there are too many errors for core.h file. Some errors;

```
Type 'std::experimental::basic_string_view<Char>' could not be resolved
Invalid overload of 'parse_format_specs'
Return has value, in function returning void
```

There are errors like these. The software compiles and runs, but there are errors in both main and library files. Likewise, I did the same compiling and installing to use the library named spdlog. It also compiles and works, but a lot of errors occur. Am I missing something in the cmake processes? There are always errors when I import an external library. How can I solve it?

Comment: `std::experimental::basic_string_view`? You seem to use the very old GCC. Fmtlib or Eclipse detects it as very old.  Renew it from here https://www.msys2.org/

Comment: Please don't copy the header and libraries, use it from the installed location instead.

Comment: I don't understand this `It also compiles and works, but a lot of errors occur.` How can it compile and work if lots of errors occur? This seems contradictory.

Comment: If you are on Ubuntu, run `sudo apt install libfmt-dev`. Run `sudo make uninstall` from the downloaded files location.

Comment: @john Yes, I think it's weird. Build finished with 0 errors, 0 warning. But in the fmt::print command, print is underlined in red. When I go into Core.h, errors appear in many places.

Comment: @Onur94 That sounds like *intellisense* errors. If the compiler is saying you're ok, then you're ok. But obviously you should fix your intellisense settings.

Comment: @273K I can't use apt install because I will use this project on linux without internet access. I need to move the library within the project.

Comment: You can download pkg with dependencies with `apt`. It's useful to learn tools available in your working environment. Otherwise you make it dirty with untrackable files.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Instead of copying as you said I used it directly from the location installed in /usr/local/ . But the problem is the same.

Comment: @273K I am using ubuntu version 18.04 and g++ version 7.5.0. I think this is the latest g++ version for ubuntu 18.04.